# Prove that if lim f(x) =L as x approches 0 then lim f(1/x) = L as x approches infinity

Tags: limits

is there a way to prove this Without using the definition of limits? and is coverse of this true? By the way it is not necessary to avoid the definition of limits if you want to use that it's fine

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the definition of a limit?

Comment: no specific reason...just wondering....can you prove it By using the definition of limits?

Comment: rename $y=1/x$, and you get $\lim f(y) =L$ as $y\rightarrow 0$, here we are not considering the sign, otherwise you need to specify how approching to 0.

Comment: but how would I prove that f(y) = L as y aproches 0